# Import self made package issues

Tags: python

Hey guys I am trying to import a self made package. I currently have the structure below

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── unifipy
│   ├── connect.py
│   ├── exceptions.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   └── tests.py
└── venv
```

all I am trying to do is import the package into my tests file

```py
import unittest
import unifipy
```

However I keep having a module exception saying it can't be found

I have tried moving tests.py out of the directory and putting it one level up but it doesn't help

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is the top-level directory in your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: not entirely sure how to check my pythonpath / or set it?

Comment: in what file are you trying to import? where is it in relation to this structure?